# Ply Lex parsing problem

Tags: parsing, lex, ply

I'm using ply as my lex parser. My specifications are the following :

```
t_WHILE = r'while'  
t_THEN = r'then'  
t_ID = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'  
t_NUMBER = r'\d+'  
t_LESSEQUAL = r'<='  
t_ASSIGN = r'='  
t_ignore  = r' \t'
```

When i try to parse the following string :

```
"while n <= 0 then h = 1"
```

It gives following output :

```
LexToken(ID,'while',1,0)  
LexToken(ID,'n',1,6)  
LexToken(LESSEQUAL,'<=',1,8)  
LexToken(NUMBER,'0',1,11)  
LexToken(ID,'hen',1,14)      ------> PROBLEM!  
LexToken(ID,'h',1,18)  
LexToken(ASSIGN,'=',1,20)  
LexToken(NUMBER,'1',1,22)
```

It doesn't recognize the token THEN, instead it takes "hen" as an identifier.

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, I found that because of the t_ignore = r" \t", it was ignoring the letter "t" (don't ask my why!). So I removed it, and now it starting taking "then" as token.

Comment: @Karan: `r' \t'` is a *raw* string. My guess is the `\t` could not be escaped in it and it would have worked had you removed the initial `r` => `t_ignore = ' \t'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason that this didn't work is related to the way ply prioritises matches of tokens, the longest token regex is tested first.

The easiest way to prevent this problem is to match identifiers and reserved words at the same type, and select an appropriate token type based on the match. The following code is similar to an example in the [ply documentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn6)

```
import ply.lex

tokens = [ 'ID', 'NUMBER', 'LESSEQUAL', 'ASSIGN' ]
reserved = {
    'while' : 'WHILE',
    'then' : 'THEN'
}
tokens += reserved.values()

t_ignore    = ' \t'
t_NUMBER    = '\d+'
t_LESSEQUAL = '\<\='
t_ASSIGN    = '\='

def t_ID(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
    if t.value in reserved:
        t.type = reserved[ t.value ]
    return t

def t_error(t):
    print 'Illegal character'
    t.lexer.skip(1)

lexer = ply.lex.lex()
lexer.input("while n <= 0 then h = 1")
while True:
    tok = lexer.token()
    if not tok:
        break
    print tok
```

Answer (score 4):

PLY prioritizes the tokens declared as simple strings according the longest regular expression, but the tokens declared as functions have their order prioritized.

From the docs:

> When building the master regular expression, rules are added in the
>   following order:
>
> 1. All tokens defined by functions are added in the same order as they appear in the lexer file.
> 2. Tokens defined by strings are added next by sorting them in order of decreasing regular expression length (longer expressions are added
>      first).

So, an alternative solution would be simply to specify the tokens you want prioritized as functions, instead of strings, like so:

```
def t_WHILE(t): r'while'; return t
def t_THEN(t): r'then'; return t
t_ID = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
t_NUMBER = r'\d+'
t_LESSEQUAL = r'<='
t_ASSIGN = r'='
t_ignore = ' \t'
```

This way WHILE and THEN will be the first rules to be added, and you get the behaviour you expected.

As a side note, you were using `r' \t'` (raw string) for t_ignore, so Python was treating the `\` as a backslash. It should be a simple string instead, as in the example above.