# special-case lexer rule in ply

Tags: python, lexer, ply

Is there a way to special-case a ply lexer rule?

```
t_IDENT     = r'[a-zA-Z_][0-9a-zA-Z_]*'
t_OPERATOR  = r'[<>=/*+-]+'
t_DEFINE    = r'='
t_PRODUCES  = r'=>'
```

I want to define an operator as any combination of the listed characters, *except* that `=` and `=>` have their own special cases. For example:

```
a + b
# IDENT('a') OPERATOR('+') IDENT('b') 

a ++=--> b
# IDENT('a') OPERATOR('++=-->') IDENT('b') 

a == b
# IDENT('a') OPERATOR('==-->') IDENT('b') 

a => b
# IDENT('a') PRODUCES('=>') IDENT('b') 

a = b
# IDENT('a') DEFINE('=') IDENT('b') 

a >= b
# IDENT('a') OPERATOR('>=') IDENT('b') 

a <=> b
# IDENT('a') OPERATOR('<=>') IDENT('b')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ply Lex parsing problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022129/ply-lex-parsing-problem)

Comment: Never mind, this is essentially the same as the reserved word problem in the above SO question, also in the docs here: http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the automated `t_DEFINE` and `t_PRODUCES` rules and used the reserved word technique to handle the special cases:

```
special_operators = {'=': 'DEFINE',
                     '=>': 'PRODUCES'}

def t_OPERATOR(t):
    r'[<>=/*+-]+'
    t.type = special_operators.get(t.value, t.type)
    return t
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the reason you get `OPERATOR` tokens instead of expected `PRODUCES`/`DEFINE` is token precedence rules of PLY lexer:

> Internally, lex.py uses the `re` module to do its patten matching. When
>   building the master regular expression, rules are added in the
>   following order:
>
> 1. All tokens defined by functions are added in the same order as they
>      appear in the lexer file.
> 2. Tokens defined by strings are added next by
>      sorting them in order of decreasing regular expression length (**longer
>      expressions are added first**).

Just convert certain rules into functions:

```
def t_DEFINE(t):
    r'='
    return t

def t_PRODUCES(t):
    r'=>'
    return t
```